# more verbose git cherry

Tags: git, git-log, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick

I'm looking for git cherry to behave more like `git log`.

I have two independent branches in my git repository (result of svn import). No common ancestor, no merges between them. I don't want these two branches to be ever connected, even though they concern the same project.

The two branches are:

`master` (clean line, releasable code)

`old_trunk` (junk development branch, with experimental commits as well as ones that I want to cherry pick)

Now,

```
$ git cherry old_trunk -v
```

properly identifies changesets that were already applied to the master (as svn merge is working more like a cherry pick).

However git log:

```
$ git log --cherry --cherry-mark master..old_trunk
```

shows all commits as not yet applied to master.
It's either broken or using different mechanism to find cherry picks.

I'm looking for a solution to navigate through `old_trunk` history to see the author, see the date of the commit, see full commit message, and most importantly to be able to distinguish cherry-picks already done.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can list all the commits with `git cherry` and then run them through a loop to show each one returned. Would something like this work for you?

```
for i in $(git cherry old_trunk | cut -d" " -f 2); do git show $i --quiet --pretty=fuller; done
```

Comment: This is very good. I also found log alternative: `git log --no-walk --oneline $(git cherry old_trunk|grep "^+"|cut -d" " -f2)` which is probably a little better in answering my question. However for loop will be more suitable for my needs. Thanks!